# "cannot find symbol: __FastDevLauncher" blocking deployment to Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin-studio, xamarin.android

I'm porting a Windows Phone app to Android using Xamarin Studio and MonoGame.

Set up has gone very smoothly, but when I try to deploy the project to the emulator, I get the following errors:

---

```
C:\Users\croberts\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Shelter_Port\Shelter_Android\Shelter_Android\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\TrialSplashScreen60e2a7ae51784c7983049dbf7b06b10c.java(101,101): Error:  cannot find symbol

symbol  : class __FastDevLauncher

location: package mono.android

Intent intent = new Intent (TrialSplashScreen60e2a7ae51784c7983049dbf7b06b10c.this, mono.android.__FastDevLauncher.class);
```

---

I haven't been able to find anything when google searching that mentions the __FastDevLauncher class, and the TrialSplashScreen#####.java suggests maybe it's something to do with my using the 30 day trial of Xamarin?

Regardless, I'm stumped as to where to start looking for a fix as it's not anything directly referenced in my code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Chris

Comment: For sure the error is within xamarin.  Querying a site more dedicated to their (brand new) product would probably be more expeditious.  However, posting a response back after afterwards could be useful for many.

Comment: Will do. I've contacted their support, and they advised me to try here whilst I'm waiting. I'll post a response when I have one.

Comment: OK... It seems that there were compatibility issues between the latest Xamarin release and the latest packaged MonoGame installer on their site. Building the MonoGame libraries from newer source fixes the problem and there was a HotFix issued for linking issues between the 2. It seems that what I was seeing was a bizarre manifestation of that. More info available here: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/1431

Answer (score 0):

Building the MonoGame libraries from source fixes this issue. It seems there was a linking error between the Xamarin 2.0 release and the MonoGame 3.0.0.0 release. I downloaded the latest stable source for MonoGame and built the libraries alongside my own source and the build error vanished.